# how to deselect all element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I want to deselect (remove selected element ).I am using jstree in my demo .So I read the plugin api .
[http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=deselect_all([supress_event])](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=deselect_all%28%5bsupress_event%5d%29).
But it not deleselect the selected item.
I follow the these steps
1) Click the "b" node.then "b" node is selected.
2) Then press "deselect" button but it not deselect the items.

```
$('#deselect').click(function(){

    alert('--')
    $('#tree').deselect_all(true)

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/150/

Comment: i used easyui plugin if u want try this....http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/tree/tree4.php

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('#tree').jstree("deselect_all");
```

Insted of

```
$('#tree').deselect_all(true)
```

Here is <kbd>[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/152/)</kbd>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/153/ .In this fiddle I am using functionality of go one level up

Comment: I need to disable button when It is on top .

Comment: I follow the steps 1) I expand "b" node select "b-a" node.Then click "open level button".It goes to "b".but then I click again it don't do anything .it should become disable

Answer (score 1):

I just learned that you can also use:

`$('#tree').jstree("deselect_all", true);`

This will suppress the 'changed.jstree' event, which is what I needed for my page, and seems to be more along the lines of your original logic.

My working code excerpt verbatim:

```
function DeselectTree() {
    $('[id ^= "forms-foldertree-"]').each(function () {
        $(this).jstree('deselect_all', true);
    });
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, its very clean and concise.  Seems like it's super efficient.

Answer (score 0):

What I use,

> $('#deselect').click(function(){
>
> $('#tree').attr("checked", false);
>
> })

or you can add custom attributes and give stylesheet/class for select/deselect

by jquery change this

> $('#deselect').click(function(){
>
> if($('#tree').attr("customattr") == "select" )
>
> ```
>    $('#tree').attr("customattr", "unselect");
> ```
>
> else
>
> ```
> $('#tree').attr("customattr", "select");
> ```
>
> })